# GRE Geometry Reference Request?

Tags: reference-request, geometry, usa

My brother is taking the normal GRE (not the math subject test), and I need to help him learn geometry. I know basic geometry myself, but I need a book that will present it well and will have good exercises. Any suggestions are appreciated.

It seems to me the GRE covers about 50% of U.S. highschool geometry.

Topics in the GRE include:

- Vertical angles
- Parallel lines with a transverse
- Area of "slices" of circles
- Exterior angles of triangles
- Similar Triangles
- Triangles inscribed in circles

etc.

Answer (score 5):

There are many resources on this topic, most of which are profit-making and at some point require a fee.
At least one exception is the linking of the GRE topics to the relevant Kahn Academy videos: [***link here***](https://support.khanacademy.org/hc/en-us/community/posts/5226512153741-GRE-Prep-According-to-ETS).

Also, ETS itself offers a free review package, with sample questions: [***PDF download***](https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/gre_math_review.pdf).

[image: GRE Figs]


<sup>Figures from GRE Math Review.</sup>

---

Comment: @Ovi: Both links work for me. I made the links more ***prominent***.

Comment: Ah yes I was able to access those, but you said "There are many resources here, most of which are profit-making...". I am a little confused as to what the "here" refers to.

Comment: @Ovi: By "here" I mean on this topic. If you search you will find many sites offering review help, but for a fee. I did not bother linking to them. Just search for "GRE geometry review."

Comment: Okay thanks got it

Comment: Looks like the ETS link is broken now, but searching for "gre ets khan" brings me to [this discussion](https://support.khanacademy.org/hc/en-us/community/posts/5226512153741-GRE-Prep-According-to-ETS) on the KA page. This looks to be the same list that was linked, based on [this 2016 snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20161121061437/https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/prepare/khan_academy) from the Wayback Machine.

Comment: @NickC: Thanks for finding the updated link.